# Entity Framework - Update a row in a table

Tags: c#, frameworks, ado.net, entity

I am new to Entity Framework and i have a question regarding updating data in a table.

Currently, I am using the following approach to update data and looking for a better way if somebody can help me out.

Let's say I am updating "Category" table and it has only 3 fields(id, name, archived)

```
private void UpdateCategory(category entity)
{
    category  catObj = context.category.find(e=> e.id == id);
    catObj.name = entity.name;
    catObj.archived = entity.archived;
    context.savechanges();
}
```

My question is if there are 50 fields in category table I will have to assign each field individually. Can't i do something like this .. catObj = entity; ?

Comment: Why is the `entity` parameter not tracked?

Comment: @Tauseef If you solved this please put an answer. I'm also facing the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

To do this automatically you could probably use a project such as [AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/).

However you have to be careful with this, because if a property doesn't have a value for the category being passed in, it will overwrite the old category's property with the non-value, even if it's not intended.  To get around this you will have to use automapper configurations to do the projection correctly, exactly as you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the properties of all members of a collection with a single LINQ operation:

```
collection.Select(c => {c.PropertyToSet = value; return c;}).ToList();
```

So:

```
private void UpdateCategory(category entity)
{
    category  catObj = context.category.find(e=> e.id == id);
    catObj.Select(c=> {c.name = entity.name; c.archived = entity.archived; return c;}).ToList();
    context.savechanges();
}
```

Comment: still i will have to write or assign all 50 fields manually. i was wondering can i do obj = obj rather than assigning every single property of an object.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that AutoMapper is good for your purpose. Also you may have to specify mappings anyway.

For what you described, I usually have a method such as `void CopyEntityFrom(Category Source)` in each entity and in the method, I have mapping statements (e.g. `this.name = entity.name;` ) But I do this not by hand but generate them using MVCScaffolding or other code generation techniques.